# Is there a way to get the language direction (RTL/LTR)?

Tags: android

I want to align the content of a TextView according to the language (use gravity=right for Hebrew, Arabic etc.) I tried to find either a resource folder suffix such as layout-ltr or some API to help me set the gravity programatically, but I couldn't find any. Is there a generic way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource identifier you should use is ldrtl, but before, you need to indicate that your app support RTL language by adding android:supportsRtl="true" to your manifest. Android offers even offers a complete API for RTL language. You can find information about it at http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html